# Coin Change Optimization

Tags: dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search, greedy, coin-change

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Suppose I have a set of n coins {a_1, a2, ..., a_n}. A coin with value
>   1 will always appear. What is the minimum number of coins I
>   need to reach M?
>
> The constraints are:
>
> - 1 ≤    n ≤ 25
> - 1 ≤   m ≤ 10^6
> - 1 ≤ a_i ≤ 100

Ok, I know that it's the Change-making problem.
I have tried to solve this problem using Breadth-First Search, Dynamic Programming and Greedly (which is incorrect, since it don't always give best solution). However, I get Time Limit Exceeded (3 seconds).

So I wonder if there's an optimization for this problem.
The description and the constraints called my attention, but I don't know how to use it in my favour:

- A coin with value 1 will always appear.
- 1 ≤ a_i ≤ 100

I saw at wikipedia that this problem can also be solved by "Dynamic programming with the probabilistic convolution tree". But I could not understand anything.

Can you help me?
This problem can be found here: http://goo.gl/nzQJem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `a_n` be the largest coin. Use these two clues:

- result is `>= ceil(M/a_n)`,
- result configuration has lot of `a_n's`.

It is best to try with maximum of `a_n's` and than check if it is better result with less `a_n's` till it is possible to find better result.

Something like: let `R({a_1, ..., a_n}, M)` be function that returns result for a given problem. Than `R` can be implemented:

```
num_a_n = floor(M/a_n)
best_r = num_a_n + R({a_1, ..., a_(n-1)}, M-a_n*num_a_n)
while num_a_n > 0:
  num_a_n = num_a_n - 1
  # Check is it possible at all to get better result
  if num_a_n + ceil(M-a_n*num_a_n / a_(n-1) ) >= best_r:
     return best_r
  next_r = num_a_n + R({a_1, ..., a_(n-1)}, M-a_n*num_a_n)
  if next_r < best_r:
    best_r = next_r
return best_r
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement this, it's fast in some cases, but it's slow in others. Then I tried put memozation, but it becomes O(n*m).

Comment: I think that memoization it can be done in O(n * min(M, a_n*a_{n-1})). It is not needed to search below M-a_n*a_{n-1}.

Comment: very clever solution! Now I got AC. Thank you very much!